# How do you share DLC across multiple profiles?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-2

I have purchased DLC on my profile and I am able to access it fine but my brother wants to have access to the DLC on his profile. The DLC is located on the same system but I can't seem to find a way to share it. Is there a way?

Comment: What platform is this on? If it's XBox you may have a way, but not on PC.

Comment: The platform is Xbox 360.

Answer (score 3):

On Xbox, who can use DLC depends on who bought it and which console has the licenses.

The easiest way to be sure is to sign your account into a second controller. This will allow your brother to access the DLC.

If you are trying to use the DLC on the system that you used to buy it, then he should already be able to use it. If this is the case, I recommend contacting Xbox Support.

Lastly, if you bought the DLC on a different Xbox, like an old one for example, then This link explains how to transfer the license to the new system:
http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Support/LicenseMigration/Home

Answer (score 0):

DLC on Steam (Live also?) is tied to the account, regardless of the presence (or absence) of the physical data. Strictly speaking, there's no way your brother can get to it without purchasing it for himself.

But, as a brother myself, I suggest a simpler suggestion -- let him make a character on your account!

Comment: For Xbox, if the two accounts are on the same physical console, both can access the DLC.

Comment: I have it on XBox it seems that DLC is not crossing over.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same as if you were to buy a "live arcade" game. That game belongs to your account only so I'm afraid your brother won't people to access something you have purchased.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried signing in with both profiles at the same time (with 2 controllers)?

You can play Live Arcade games bought from another account this way.